# Class view with post, get and data

Tags: python, django

I have practically finished the microblogging application and I want to change to class base views now. I read about generic views, but it looks like each of them has specific properties. In my index view I display two models and two forms, so I created IndexView (View) and put the get and post functions there and it works, but it doesn't look like there are any benefits of class views, so I'm probably doing something wrong. Currently, several views repeat a lot of code, and I thought that class views would solve this problem. I would like an example of how such a view should be written as class view with reusable get.

```
class IndexView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_form = AddPostForm()
        comment_form = AddCommentForm()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            logged_user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            blocked_users = logged_user.blocked.all()
            posts = Post.objects.exclude(author__in=blocked_users)
            print(blocked_users)
            posts = posts.order_by('-pub_date')
        else:
            posts = Post.objects.all()
            posts = posts.order_by('-pub_date')

        comments = Comment.objects.all()
        comments = comments.order_by("-pub_date")

        return render(request, 'mikroblog/index.html', {'posts': posts, 'comments': comments,
                                                    'post_form': post_form, 'comment_form': comment_form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post_form = AddPostForm(request.POST)
            comment_form = AddCommentForm(request.POST)
            if post_form.is_valid():
                new_post = post_form.save(commit=False)
                new_post.author = request.user
                new_post.tags = ''
                content = ''
                for word in new_post.content_post.split():
                    if '#' in word:
                        new_post.tags += f"{word} "
                        content += f"{word} "
                    else:
                        content += f"{word} "

                new_post.content_post = content
                new_post.save()

                for word in content.split():
                    if '@' in word:
                        print(word)
                        user_to_notificate = CustomUser.objects.get(username=word[1:])

                        new_notification = TalkAbout()
                        new_notification.where = new_post
                        new_notification._from = new_post.author
                        new_notification.to = user_to_notificate
                        new_notification.sended = False
                        print(new_notification)
                        new_notification.save()

                post_form = AddPostForm()

            if comment_form.is_valid():
                new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                new_comment.author = request.user
                new_comment.save()
                comment_form = AddCommentForm()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class-based views and override the 'post' and 'get' methods if you need to.
Follow this link:
[Django CBVs documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Comment: I did it like in my edited post, but should it look like this?

Comment: @Szafran It's almost true. But it depends on the business and sometimes it doesn't need to be overridden and can be done with generic classes.